# Pi-hole not accepting local DNS

Tags: networking, dns, pi-hole

I have setup pi-hole on a local linux server using docker-compose, the server uses the local IP 192.168.x.123. Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "81:80/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Berlin'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'mystrongwebpassword'
    volumes:
      - './etc-pihole:/etc/pihole'
      - './etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d'
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Before running the container, I had to change the `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` on my server by substituting `#DNSStubListener=yes` with `DNSStubListener=no`, else port 53 would have been blocked at the start.

Then, I configured my Speedport router to use my local server IP as DNS resolver:

[image: router configuration]

Everything seems to work quite well, as far as the output on the pi-hole admin overview shows:

[image: pi-hole admin overview]

Then, I tried to setup local DNS addresses on pi-hole to be able to access certain machines locally using domains, let's say `home.local` pointing to my server address on `192.168.x.123`:

[image: local DNS domains]

However, neither my android phone connected to my WiFi nor the Ubuntu PC I'm writing this text from is able to resolve those addresses.

I tried changing my Ubuntu computer's `resolv.conf` so it directly uses my server's DNS:

**resolv.conf on Ubtuntu computer**

```
# ...
nameserver 192.168.x.123 # before: 127.0.0.53
options # ...
search my.router         # my router's local FQDN
# ...
```

After doing that, I am able to connect to `home.local` on the Ubuntu PC, however I'm unable to resolve the real LAN hostnames. Let's say my server's hostname is `johndoe` and before changing the `nameserver` in `resolv.conf` I was perfectly able to connect to my server via `http://johndoe/` but changing the nameserver makes it unaccessible.

Is there something I have to take care of when configuring pi-hole so the local DNS resolving works "out of the box", so that every device is automatically able to resolve the local DNS entries?

Here's what my `/etc/pihole/custom.list` looks like:

```
192.168.x.xxx senec.local
192.168.x.123 home.local
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: I "dag into it" a bit:

```
$ dig home.local
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> home.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 52863
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;home.local.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 10:17:53 CET 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 37

$ dig @192.168.x.123 home.local
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> @192.168.x.123 home.local
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60551
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;home.local.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
home.local.     0   IN  A   192.168.x.123

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.x.123#53(192.168.x.123) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 10:18:34 CET 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

So apparently when manually setting the DIG resolver in `dig` the resolving of the local DNS entries set in pi-hole works. Still this is not the behavior I want since I expect my configuration to work without settings DNS resolvers manually in every device I use.